# Running Ember Tests in the terminal: Console log not working

Tags: ember.js

I am working on an ember 2.8 project and I am a newbie.  On top of this, we are using a docker container to run in pc because we don't have a mac.  So I running the qunit tests and am unable to go to /tests to see the tests in the browser.  Because of Docker they break.

I must run 'ember test' in the terminal and view the output.

However I am finding it quite difficult to debug, the console.logs and qUnit.logs do not output to the terminal and I can't get the ms code debugger to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: hello! and welcome!

Let's focus on getting `/tests` working because that'll be the fastest feedback loop for your debugging experience.

When you say "Because of Docker, they break" -- can you expand on that?

Comment: In order for the code to work on a PC they created a mac or linux docker container and there is an extension in MS Code that loads the docker container with the repo files inside.  I don't know more than that b/c I just started work at this new place.

Comment: I mean, docker should be fine, it's complex, but nothing stops you from visiting `/tests`. The docker container needs to `EXPOSE` the port that the dev server runs on `4200` by default.

Aside from docker though -- on windows you can try wsl2, which is way better than native windows dev.